# What does it mean for a subbundle of a vector bundle to be well-defined?

Tags: vector-bundles

It's taken from the following picture(book"Riemann-Finsler geometry" by Chern & shen):
[image: valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [uplooder.net](http://www.uplooder.net/img/image/66/15fc1623861ee81f8b2caa3fed1bb26e/2.jpg))</sub>

What is their mean of the following sentence?

> $HTM:= span \{\frac{\delta}{\delta x^i}\}$ is a well-defined subbundle of $T(TM_0)$.

What does it mean for a subbundle of a vector bundle to be well-defined? How could I check it?

Thanks.

Comment: The book is defining the horizontal and vertical splittings of the tangent bundle induced by the covariant derivative. But it is doing so in local coordinates. Being well-defined means that the definition does not depend on the choice of coordinates; you must check that.